# Prediction in multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, r, predictive-modeling, random-forest, naive-bayes-classifier

**Context:** I need to make an multiclass classification to predict what type of sentence(law) the case will have in the end.

**Data:** I Have several columns to predict the case:client, cause of action, state and some columns of types of court.
My target column is well balanced, and all the columns are categorical (strings)

**code 1:** My code in R of naive-Bayes:

```
library(e1071)
model <- naiveBayes(myfile4[,-5], as.factor(myfile4[,5]))
prediction <- predict(model, newdata = myfile4[,-5])
prediciton_Bayes <- as.data.frame(prediction)
prediciton_Bayes <- cbind(myfile4$sentenca,prediciton_Bayes)
colnames(prediciton_Bayes) <- c("Sentenca","Predicao")
prediciton_Bayes

hits <- 0
for (row in 1:nrow(prediciton_Bayes)) {
  if (prediciton_Bayes$Sentenca[row] == prediciton_Bayes$Predicao[row]) {
    hits <- hits + 1
  }
}

correctness_Bayes <- hits/length(prediciton_Bayes$Sentenca)

correctness_Bayes
```

**Code 2:** My code of random forest in R:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(123)
sample_indices <- sample(1:nrow(myfile4), 0.7*nrow(myfile4)) 
train_data <- myfile4[sample_indices, ]
test_data <- myfile4[-sample_indices, ]
train_data$sentenca <- as.factor(train_data$sentenca)
model <- randomForest(sentenca ~ ., data = train_data)

predictions <- predict(model, test_data)

accuracy <- mean(predictions == test_data$sentenca)
print(paste("Accuracy:", accuracy))

predictions
```

**Problem:** Both have low precision, 0.40 and 0.33 respectively.

**Question:** What i can do to increase precision? i'm starting in data science and im kinda lost in this part of make the code/model better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should normalize your data before fitting it to the ML algorithms. You can follow [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-normalize-and-standardize-data-in-r/)  as a reference.

Comment: How can i normalize data that is string?

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice your features are categorical. If they are categorical and you are using some encoding (i.e. [OHE](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)), then normalizing wouldn't make sense.